# Start Netsh in c++ application

Tags: c++, boost, netsh

I am developing an application to start hosted networks on Windows and can't get Netsh to run in the background. I've tried `ShellExecute()` but that didn't work, would boost.process get the job done and how

Comment: How did it not work? You can't start the `netsh.exe` or you can't pass the arbitrary script to a terminal via `ShellExecute` API?

Comment: I can't start Netsh

Comment: `ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"netsh.exe",NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

Comment: Sw_SHOWNORMAL shows the cmd window, and I wouldn't be able to interact with the process

Comment: I want the Windows hidden when the command executes

Comment: In that case you should do some reading on the [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) and [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) functions.